# Add Image to my Base Docker Image

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker base image that runs CentOS 6.5. This image is saved on my computer. I could not find anything that talks about how to add more images into this base image. So for example I have this base image of CentOS6.5, I need too add postgresql 9.3, and php too this base image. Is there a way once you already have a base image made, to add more packages too that base image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the whole purpose of the Docker file : build something on top of an image.

1. Create your **[dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/)**
2. Build the new image and tag it with `docker build -t <tag> <path/to/build/context>`
3. Then if you want to share it, push it to your private registry or to the docker hub to make it world accessible (`docker push <tag>`).

The build context of step 2 is the parent directory of your Dockerfile. For instance if you run the command in the directory where your dockerfile is it would be `docker build -t <tag> .`.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I have managed to accomplish my goals thanks too your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from) and docker build to do this e.g.:

```
FROM yourCentos
MAINTAINER your name
RUN yum install ...
CMD ...
```

And then `docker build -t="myImage" .` in the direcotry where you created the dockerfile.

Or you can upgrade youe images via [CLI](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#creating-our-own-images) (not the preferd way!!) and commit them.